# Path to target output file

Tags: cmake

I have a .so library target created by `add_library`, and need to pass an absolute path to this library to an external script. Now I have `${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}/${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX}LangShared${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}` for that (`LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH` is defined in my `CMakeLists.txt`). This looks like hard-coding to me, because it will break as soon as the target is renamed or some of its properties are changed. Is there a way to get an absolute path to `add_library`'s output?

Answer (score 88):

You should use a [generator expression](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) for this.

From the docs for [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/add_custom_command.html) and the docs for generator expressions:

> Arguments to `COMMAND` may use "generator expressions"...
>
> Generator expressions are evaluted during build system generation to produce information specific to each build configuration.

In this case, assuming your library target is called "MyLib", the generator expression representing the full path to the built library would be:

```
$<TARGET_FILE:MyLib>
```

Comment: This is very frustrating because none of the `add_custom_[...]` commands allow you to invoke macros - they can only run external programs.

Comment: Yeah, to invoke a macro you'd need to add it to a standalone CMake script file and invoke CMake itself from the command using the `-P` arg.  The downside (apart from being overly complex) is that the macro in the script file doesn't have access to any of the current variables in the main CMake process - you need to pass them too when invoking CMake.  So for example `add_custom_command(... COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} -P"path/to/script_with_macro.cmake")`

Comment: Or, if used in a cmake-macro, `$<TARGET_FILE:${target_macro_parameter}>` .

Comment: Generator expressions only work as arguments to a few functions related to the "generation" step.  If you want this during the "configuration" step, generator expressions don't work.  See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470020/cmake-how-to-get-target-location-for-install-rule

Answer (score 31):

Try:

```
get_property(fancy_lib_location TARGET fancy_lib PROPERTY LOCATION)
message (STATUS "fancy_lib_location == ${fancy_lib_location}")
```

Where `fancy_lib` is the target created with `add_library (fancy_lib SHARED ...)`.

I found that works directly with Makefile generators, but there is more work to be done for Visual Studio generators since the value of `fancy_lib_location` is not what you would expect:

1. `fancy_lib_location` will contain an embedded reference to a Visual-Studio-specific `$(OutDir)` reference that you will have to replace with the value of the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` CMake variable (which resolves to something like `Debug`, or `Release`).
2. At least for CMake 2.8.1, and at least on Visual Studio targets, and if you have set the `CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX` variable, then it will **not** be included in the value (which may or may not be a bug, I don't know).

Comment: For point 1, you have available the per-configuration versions of `LOCATION`, i.e. `LOCATION_DEBUG`, `LOCATION_RELEASE`, etc.  This resolves the path fully.  For point 2, this seems to be fixed as at v2.8.10

Comment: @Fraser in fact `LOCATION_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}` seems to cover all cases (i.e. even when `${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}` is "", it correctly returns the path to the release target).

Comment: @Ose Unfortunately, ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} is only supported in make-based generators, so your solution is likely to break when using an IDE like Visual Studio.

Comment: Policy [CMP0026](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0026.htm) in Cmake 3.0 and later) disallows using the LOCATION property in this manner. The generator expression method is preferred.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone The problem with generators is that you can't use variables in the generator name. `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${targetname}>` produces that as literal text.

Comment: @Qix [According to this link, you can use variables.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#string-valued-generator-expressions) They give an example: `$<$<BOOL:${prop}>:-I$<JOIN:${prop}, -I>>` I'm wondering if you hit a bug or if this is a new feature.

Comment: Seeng as how those are all generator values, I would imagine you can use generators within generators (a generator is `$<...>` as opposed to `${...}`, which is a variable).

Comment: with cmake v3.15.5, this gives following error:  The LOCATION property may not be read from target.  Use the target name directly with add_custom_command, or use the generator expression $<TARGET_FILE>, as appropriate.

Comment: @harish I've not used cmake in years and so my answer may now be badly out of date, and thus now "stale".

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer by @bgooddr, here is a CMake function to get the location of a target:

```
function(get_fancy_lib_location)
    set(options)
    set(multiValueArgs LIB)
    set(oneValueArgs LOCATION)
    cmake_parse_arguments(get_fancy_lib_location "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN} )
    message (STATUS "fancy_lib  == ${get_fancy_lib_location_LIB}")

    get_property(fancy_lib_location TARGET "${get_fancy_lib_location_LIB}" PROPERTY LOCATION)
    message (STATUS "fancy_lib_location == ${fancy_lib_location}")

    set(${get_fancy_lib_location_LOCATION} ${fancy_lib_location})
endfunction()
```