# How to get target install location from CMake?

Tags: cmake

I would like to create a "post-install" script for my CMake build, but for this I need the install location for a given target.

For example:

```
function(post_install_target target)
    set(target_install_loc ???) # Somehow
    message("Target install location is ${target_install_loc}")
endfunction(post_install_target)

# ...

post_install_target(A) # Some target defined elsewhere.
```

This could print:

```
-- Target install location is /usr/local/lib/libA.so
```

I already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470020/cmake-how-to-get-target-location-for-install-rule), (by using `$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>`) but the result is the location in the build tree, not in the install tree (i.e. it prints `/home/me/project/build/libA.so`).

Answer (score -2):

The variable responsible for the installation path is CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, try it, its default value should be /usr/local/ [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html)

Comment: Yes, CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is part of the answer. But I also need the path after the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, the DESTINATION directory, for example, `lib`, `bin`, etc...
I am using a framework which store some of my targets in `${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/lib/framework-${SOMEVAR}/plugins` that I would like to retreive.

Comment: In this section of the documentation you will find all the minor variables used during installation. [cmake install documentations](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#command:install). For example CMAKE_INSTALL_BIN - <install prefix> bin folder. But if you install in specific directories - you will have to save these paths to variables in advance and manually.