# How to get the path where .so or .a files have been generated by cmake in android?

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk

I am trying to use [this library](https://github.com/janbar/openssl-cmake) in android using NDK. The thing is I add the library with `add_subdirectory` command, like this, `cpp/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(openssl)
message(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) #for logging
```

And it gets build successfully but the output of message command is `C:/Users/gandalf/AndroidStudioProjects/CPRTest4/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a`
And the directory and it's subdirectories do not contain the `.a` or `.so` files that are supposed to be generated. The mentioned .a or .so files are put in this directory `C:\Users\gandalf\AndroidStudioProjects\CPRTest4\app\build\intermediates\stripped_native_libs\debug\out\lib\x86_64`. How can I get the second address of bin directory using cmake variables?

I know that when you use `add_library()` some cmake variables like `<project>_BIN_DIR` is initialized. Are there any equivalent variables for when you use `add_subdirectory`?
Can add_library instead of `add_subdirectory`, be used for building this library?

Comment: How about checking the [`OUTPUT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html#prop_tgt:OUTPUT_NAME) property of the target?

Comment: would you give an example please?

Comment: Example of getting library's full path using [LOCATION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/LOCATION.html) property: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4481942/3440745.