# Is it possible to get the target filename in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to copy several targets into a specific build directory using the `add_custom_command` which is as follows:

```
get_filename_component(buildDirRelFilePath "libDetector_dynamic.so"
                       REALPATH BASE_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
add_custom_command(
        TARGET Detector_dynamic POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                ${buildDirRelFilePath}
                ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/libDetector_dynamic.so)
```

It's very desirable to simply remove all the hardcoded values that refer to the target being built and instead use a CMake's variable that changes automatically for each target.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Path to target output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346281/path-to-target-output-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So use generator expressions.

```
add_library(Detector_dynamic ...)
add_custom_command(
    TARGET Detector_dynamic POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
            $<TARGET_FILE:Detector_dynamic>
            ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/)
```

I do not think there's ever need to reference the filename by the name. For me it looks like you should use `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` or just maybe just write `install` scripts.

Comment: yes, I am using the install, and it works just fine, except that it strips the lib references. on a side note, aside from that, is there a way to avoid libDetector_dynamic?
and somehow write `Detector_dynamic` which is the `target` here and get its file name?

Comment: `$<TARGET_FILE:libDetector_dynamic>`

Comment: if I use this as is, will it work under windows as well? cause the `libSth` is unique to unix systems and under windows its not a different name. thats why I thought maybe I can use `Detector_dynamic` instead of the `libDetector_dynamic` which is a linux specific name I believe .

Comment: Och, that `lib` prefix. It's a typo on my side. If the target is `Detector_dynamic` then use `$<TARGET_FILE:Detector_dynamic>`. Please don't trust me - read the documentation instead to be sure :p I assumed the target is named `libDetector_dynamic`. `will it work under windows as well?` Yes, cmake works on windows, cmake generator expressions work on windows too.